# Return a response in jsonp format from Flask for jQuery

Tags: python, jquery, flask

I am very new to web development back-end and my goal is to call a python script from Javascript.

Using Flask, I think I am able to host my python script on localhost port 5000
python code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sub', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_func():
   """
   I want this function to be called using javascript 
   """
```

This is how I am trying to use ajax in JavaScript to call the function

```
function logResults(json){
    console.log(json);
}    

$.ajax({
       url: "http://0.0.0.0:5000/sub",
       dataType: "jsonp",
       jsonpCallback: "logResults"
    });
```

I learned that you have to use jsonp in order to have a cross domain request. (for example I need to reach port 5000 on localhost while the javascript is running on port 9000 of localhost)

When trying to run this code, I am receiving

> Loading failed for the < script > with source “http://0.0.0.0:5000/sub?callback=logResults&_=1604937695311”.

Does anyone know where I could be making a mistake? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but does anyone know how to send a data parameter when dataType is jsonp?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:5000/sub",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "logResults"
    });
```